# What is $dx/dF(x)$ where $F(.)$ is a continuous, increasing function.

Tags: derivatives, probability-distributions, inverse

I was wondering if it is possible to find $dx/dF(x)$, that is, the derivative of $x$ with respect to $F(x)$, which is an increasing, continuous function. Does it involve finding the derivative of the inverse?

Thanks!

Comment: do you mean $dF(x)/dx$?

Comment: @gt6989b No, it is $dx/dF(x)$.

Comment: yes, then sounds like you are looking at something like $dF^{-1}(x)/dx$ or a flavor of that...

Comment: This derivative does not always exist in the classical sense; for instance it does not exist classically for a discrete variable. Instead this derivative is a distribution, or in other words it exists in the sense of distribution theory. (This is probably part of why distribution theory got its name.)

Comment: This question would be greatly enhanced if you explained what you mean by dx/dG(x) for some general (increasing) function G.

Comment: Do you want the derivative **of** $dx/dF(x)$ (presumably with respect to $F(x)$, that is, you want $d^2x/d(F(x))^2$, the _second_ derivative of $x$ with respect to $F(x)$) or do you want to know a mathematical expression or formula for $dx/dF(x)$?

Comment: @DilipSarwate The latter, an expression for $dx/dF(x)$. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Is this what you mean: $$\frac{dx}{dx}=\frac{dx}{dF(x)}\times\frac{dF(x)}{dx}=1$$ for $\frac{dF(x)}{dx}\neq0$?

Comment: Yes! Thanks! @JamesPak